# Merge adjacent polygons in sf

Tags: r, tidyverse, geospatial, r-sf, mutate

I'm trying to merge groups of adjacent polygons, but I'm getting big multipolygons with non-adjacent areas. In the code block below `plot(Matsuyama.sf)` shows a large contiguous region and a few islands, but I can't extract those geometries. How do I get those areas and geometries.

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
Matsuyama.sf <- st_read("https://geoshape.ex.nii.ac.jp/city/geojson/20210101/38/38201A1968.geojson")
Matsuyama.sf <- st_transform(Matsuyama.sf, crs=4326)
plot(Matsuyama.sf)
st_area(Matsuyama.sf)
```

I can split into hundreds of polygons, but the code options below just lump them back together into one

```
split.sf <- st_cast(Matsuyama.sf, "POLYGON") 
clumps_1.sf <- st_join(split.sf, split.sf, join = st_intersects)
clumps_2sf <- Matsuyama.sf %>% mutate(INTERSECT = st_intersects(.))
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you define which geometries you want to extract & how you want to group the polygons?

Comment: I’d like the polygons for individual islands (mostly top left) and for contiguous  Matsuyama city. (large block bottom right) Those are the solid-colored, joined polygons generated by plot(Matsuyama.sf). So I can see what I want but can’t extract it!

Comment: Does `st_cast(Matsuyama.sf, 'POLYGON')` not give you what you want?

Comment: No, `st_cast(Matsuyama.sf, 'POLYGON')` creates an sfc_POLYGON of length 196.

Comment: My question is how to use `st_union()` on that object to get about 20 objects. I think I might need a loop to "growth" the adjacent polygons

Comment: It can be done, but you have to be able to define how to group the objects.